# How to generate pseudocode from flowchart and vice versa

Tags: visio, flowchart

FYI,I have googled well, but couldn't find any clear way.

I have drawn a flowchart in MS visio. How to generate pseudocode from it?

Is there any way in visio or any other software to do that?

Comment: Interesting question, but I'm curious as to what you want it for.

Comment: Well, for accurate psudocode -> flowchart or vice versa without cross checking. I have spent several hours designing the flowchart with step by step verification. Why should I spend another few hours on the same thing + cross reference check? Since both are very much related, step by step procedure and based on logic, I tend to believe there should have some way to do it. Just don't know how.

Comment: This looks promising, if either of these tools go the other way (or you could do pseudocode first): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284376/what-or-where-is-this-basic-pseudocode-flowcharting-program?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode:

start

Declare  wholesalePrice as Integer

Declare  retailPrice as Integer

Declare profit as Integer

string END_LINE = “”

Call housekeeping()

Call detail()

Call endOfJob()
stop

housekeeping()

```
output “Enter the wholesale price”
input wholesalePrice
```

return

detail()

```
output “Enter the retail price”
input retailPrice

profit = retailPrice - wholesalePrice

output profit
```

return

endOfJob()
    output “Thanks for using this program”